# 1/3 octave audio analysis in Android app

Tags: android, audio, real-time, analysis

I am trying to create an app to do some real-time audio analysis and want to display the results in 1/3 octave range.

I found some source code here https://code.google.com/p/audio-analyzer-for-android/source/checkout

Which uses fft and displays the frequency response of the audio being received by the device, but I am struggling to wrap my head around trying to convert this into 1/3 octave values.

Does anyone how this is done?

Comment: If you have the calculated frequency, it takes you nothing to tell if it lays in the range 2-4 or 5-7 or ...

Comment: Essentially, using enough a large enough FFT, and summing the magnitude of bins together to you your 3rd octave bands.